# Firebase hosting URL needs .html to display a page

Tags: html, node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to host a website at Google Firebase.
The `index.html` is shown as (e.x.)`app.firebase.com`, but when I want to access a page like login.html I need to type `app.firebase.com/login.html`, just `app.fire-base.com/login` doesn't work. 
How would I achieve this for every `.html` file in the directory (public), do I need to configure the `firebase.json`? I read the docs but I could not find any information.

Here is my .json

```
 {
      "hosting": {
        "public": "public",
        "signin": "/signin.html"

      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not confident enough to give a full answer but I know that when I was deploying applications in firebase with emberjs, the routing (i.e. URLs like /login) was all handled by ember. So I think the reason you can't find anything is because it's the responsibility of your front-end framework.

Comment: i don't use any particular framework i followed the instuctions from getting started and i deployed through nodejs

Comment: So this might be a nodejs thing?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To omit the `.html` for all resource paths e.g. `/login.html -> /login`

- add `"cleanUrls": true` to your `.json`.
- firebase automatically redirects with a `301` code if user enters `/login.html`.

  ```
  "hosting": {
    // ...

    // Add the "cleanUrls" attribute within "hosting"
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
  ```

Read [Control `.html` extensions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#control_html_extensions) to know more.

---

For specific routing:
You can make a redirect/rewrite section in your `.json` as described in the following,

- [Configure redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects)
- [Configure rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites)

Comment: Could you provide an example for login.html , do i need to do this manually for every page?

Comment: Actually this might be better. You want to remove the html for all urls right? To do it for all paths you can add "cleanUrls": true to your json https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#cleanurls
This would remove the .html for all urls and automatically redirect for example /login.html to /login